# How to remove hash value from URL without making it scroll to top instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm removing the hash value with `parent.location.hash = ''` but that instantly makes the browser jump to the top of the page - can I just remove the `#!ajax-url-part` from the browser without making it jump to the top of the page?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/5247200

Comment: You can save your scroll-height then you can jump that height?

Comment: You can read this: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks, that was just what I needed :) You can make that an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ok! I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP wants, I put my comment in an answer because is a valid answer:

You can read this blog:

http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

The trick is as easy as this:

```
  window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))

or

window.location.href.split('#')[0]